# Add a library to CMake macOS bundle

Tags: c++, macos, qt, cmake

How can I add a libary to a macos bundle, such that it ends up in the bundle as well? The library in question is part of the project, which has two targets: a library and a
bootstrapper executable. If I make the boostrapper executable a Macos Bundle the app bundle is built and works fine but however the library is not put into the bundle. How can I achieve this?

Comment: An [mre] in the post itself would be nice ([ask])

Comment: Well I dont know how it works how can I post a MWE then.

Comment: An [mre] defining the problem. Save answerers the work of setting up the problem to solve. Yes, linking to a repo helps, but read the section in [ask] on helping others reproduce the problem.

Comment: MWE: https://github.com/ManuelSchneid3r/mini-cmake-qt6

Comment: Now I made up an MWE. It took me about an hour or two. Does it help you?

Comment: repros inline in the pot are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask]. Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them. This will help _you_- not me- get an answer to your question. You can thank yourself for doing it!

Answer (score 0):

See [fixup_bundle](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/BundleUtilities.html). It pulls the required dependencies. Not only self defined targets, but also external dependencies.

```
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DragNDrop")
set(CPACK_MONOLITHIC_INSTALL TRUE)

set(FB_APP "\${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/myapp.app")
set(FB_DIRS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}/lib ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

install(CODE "
    include(BundleUtilities)
    fixup_bundle(\"${FB_APP}\" \"\" \"${FB_DIRS}\")
")

include(CPack)
```